# Узнать, что функция вызвана через alert

Tags: javascript, функции

У меня есть одна функция, которая должна вызываться *только* через `eval` (да-да, знаю, `eval is evil`), как определить, что она вызвана через `alert`, либо через `console.log`?

Comment: А как насчёт `alert(eval("f()"))` или там `eval("alert(f())")`?

Comment: `eval`-то конечно evil, но функция, которая может быть вызвана ТОЛЬКО через eval — втройне evil.

Comment: Если это и можно как то типа `this.caller` то только в довольно старых браузерах и в не строгом режиме и наверно не в IE а вообще интересная задача пусть гуру по напрягают мозг напрямую такого метода нет но можно придумать костыли через прототипы и `caller` как я уже говорил

Comment: @tehead, лучше покажите вашу "чудо" функцию

Comment: @AlexWindHope а какая собственно разница что содержится в ф-ции можно лишь посоветовать вставить туда нужные строки

Comment: @Rules, а не лучше ли избавиться от eval чем лепить костыли?

Comment: Содержание функции особо не важно, к примеру:
fucntion f() { 
  return "AnotherFunction();";
}

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, ваша задача в том, чтобы скрыть то, что вызывается через eval, от дебагера, это заведомо дурацкая задача, и не получится. мой совет - **не заморачивайтесь, ваш код *ни кому* не нужен.** а если у вас там приватная информация то, это самый плохой способ ее скрыть.

вообще на момент вызова функции, там идет раскрытие скобок, т.е.

alert(f()); ничем не отличается от f(); для функции f, т.к. сначала вызывается f() а потом alert()

```
function test() {
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller);
    return 'console.log(1)';
}
evl(test());
```

в этом примере test() всё равно будет выполнен, несмотря на то что evl===undefined;

Answer (score 0):

Переназначаем функцию `eval`:

```
/**
 * 1 способ
 */
window['eval'] = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return new Function(data).call(this);
}

eval("alert(1)");

/**
 * 2 способ
 */
var proxied = eval;
window['eval'] = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
};

eval('alert(2)');
```

Второй способ лучше.

Comment: @lampa, на самом деле, оба способа ужасны :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope аргументируйте :)

Comment: @lampa, легко - переопределение eval'a, для того, что-бы отловить вызов функции, которая может быть вызвана только через eval, это, мягко говоря, извращение.

Проще говоря, я не сомневаюсь, что за такой гавнокод на ровном месте есть специальное место в аду.

Т.е. проблема не в ответе на вопрос, ответ правильный, проблема в глупом вопросе :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope а по моему вторая функция выглядит красиво `*_*` и далеко не говнокод)

Comment: @lampa, да вопрос не в красоте, вопрос в другом - зачем? :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope может быть автор пытается поделить на ноль и переместиться во времени?)

Comment: Мне не надо узнать, что находится внутри эвала, мне надо не допустить подмены eval на alert :)

Comment: @tehead: а что помешает написать

    window['lalala'] = window['alert'];
    lalala(f());

Расскажите лучше, какую **реальную** задачу вы решаете.